# Resolve/Close TFS Scenario only with inactive children / links

Tags: tfs

My company uses TFS 2008 with the MSF for Agile process template.  We are in the process of planning an upgrade for TFS 2010.  We use Scenarios as a container for functional requirements with linked development tasks, bugs, etc.

In order to save the state of a Scenario as 'Resolved' or 'Closed', I would like to enforce that any development task or bug that is linked to the scenario is also closed.  With TFS 2008, these are links, in TFS 2010 we plan to use child work items.

I have been reviewing the work item type definition schema and MSDN documentation, but nothing is jumping out at me as a solution to this problem.

Can it be done?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible "out of the box".  I would recommend you write a query to find cases where the "rule" is violated and handle it that way.

If you MUST automate this - You could use the TFS [Eventing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130154%28VS.90%29.aspx)  which can invoke a Web Service.

Set it up for when a Task or Bug is closed - query the database for the Scenario and if all the Task/Bugs are closed - use the TFS API to advance the Status to Resolved or Closed.  You could limit the allowed user to make advancement to the account the Service runs under.

Answer (score 0):

What you want cannot be done directly.  The saving of a work item is what is called a Notification (rather than a Decision).  That means that you can only do TFS API stuff in an event after it is done.  You cannot block it.

However, there are ways to get the "effect" of what you are looking for.  If you modified your template so that your parent work item (I think you called it Scenario) had the State control (**not the field**) as read only that would make it so that only clients that don't use the normal Visual Studio controls can change that value.  (This could be worked around by your users, but it would take some effort to break the rules).

But there is one more step.  You need to get the parent work item to "Resolved" somehow.  For this I recommend a open source tool that I wrote called TFS Aggregator. (Or if you plan to "roll your own" you could use the code there as a starting point.)

You can find TFS Aggregatoron codeplex here: http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/

It is a great tool for rolling up changes and totals to parent work items.  You could put in a rule that when your child items are all "done" to move the Parent to "Resolved".

---

**EDIT:** I realize now from your question that you have more than one type of Work Item as a child of the parent Item.  TFS Aggregator does not support that right now (but it may in the future).  It was written to aggregate tasks to Bugs or PBIs.  Still, it would probably be easier to modify the code of that project than to start from scratch.